# Difference between Priority and PriorityClass object in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, pod-priority

I know what Priority class are in k8s but could not find anything about priority object after lot of searching.

So problem is I have created a PriorityClass object in my k8s cluster and set its value to -100000 and have created a pod with this priorityClass. Now when I do kubectl describe Pod I am getting two different field

```
Priority:           0

PriorityClassName:  imagebuild-priority
```

My admission-controller throws the following error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "/tmp/tmp.4tJSpSU0dy/app.yml": 
pods "pod-name" is forbidden: the integer value of priority (0) must not be provided in pod spec; 
priority admission controller computed -1000000 from the given PriorityClass name
```

Somewhere it is setting Priority to 0 and PriorityClass trying to set it to -10000.

PriorityClass object has globalDefault: False

Command Run

`kubectl create -f app.yml`

Yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: image-builder-serviceacc
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
  serviceAccountName: {{ serviceaccount }}
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: ....
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
    - name: PATH
      value: "$PATH:/bin:/busybox/"
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
  initContainers:
  - name: init-container
    image: ....
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
    - name: PATH
      value: "$PATH:/bin:/busybox/"
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "ls" ]
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Mutating controlled will append PriorityClass

Comment: What command were you running when you encounter this error, and what does your yaml look like?

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass):

> PriorityClass also has two optional fields: globalDefault and description. The globalDefault field indicates that the value of this PriorityClass should be used for Pods without a priorityClassName. **Only one PriorityClass with globalDefault set to true** can exist in the system. If there is no PriorityClass with globalDefault set, the priority of Pods with no priorityClassName is zero.

This error means that u have collision

```
the integer value of priority (0) must not be provided in pod spec; 
priority admission controller computed -1000000 from the given PriorityClass name
```

You can fix it in 2 ways:

your should choose between **globalDefault: true** :

PriorityClass:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority-minus
value: -2000000
globalDefault: True
description: "This priority class should be used for XYZ service pods only."
```

Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx5
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx5
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  priorityClassName: high-priority-minus
```

priorityClassName **can be used here, but you dont need to**

Or with **globalDefault: false** :

You need to choose **1 option,** priorityClassName or priority in your pod as described in you'r message error.

PriorityClass:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority
value: 1000000
globalDefault: false
description: "This priority class should be used for XYZ service pods only."
```

Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx7
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx7
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  priorityClassName: high-priority
```